# Is there any cooking oil mister designed such that the oil is never in contact with plastic parts?

Tags: food-safety, equipment, oil, food-preservation, containers

Is there any cooking oil mister designed such that the oil is never in contact with plastic parts? I just don't like the possibility of having any plastic chemicals dissolved in the oil.

Comment: in my experience most, if not all, commercially available sprayers use plastic parts for the pump and pickup tube. If you get a high end sprayer they will use better "food grade" plastic that wont leech chemicals into your food.

Comment: I need some concrete recommendation. An hour of browsing on Amazon has proven me a failure to find such a "high end sprayer."

Comment: You can always disassemble it so the sprayer part isn't sitting in oil all the time .... but I actually prefer the plastic canister ones.  You can't see inside of the metal ones, so you have no clue what's going on in there.  (if it's sufficiently filled / sufficient head space / what direction the intake tube is pointing / if there's anything growing in there)

Comment: And if you really want something that never touches plastic, you'd likely have to find a metal venturi (the type of mechanism that's in old perfume bottles) or manufacture your own.

Comment: Uncork bottle.  Pour small amount of oil into pan.  Spread it around

Comment: There's a wide range of glass spray bottles on Amazon marked as BPA free, at least the UK site.  I accept these have plastic spray parts but the length of time that the oil is contact with the plastic will be extremely short and any leaching will be minimal, probably to the point of negligibility.  This could be mitigated further be cleaning down the spray parts after use and re-sealing the bottle with a screw cap.  Not all plastic is bad\harmful.

Comment: Must it be a mister? Is there a reason that you want a mister, or would another type of device be suitable?